# iOS - setIdleTimerDisabled:NO Not Working

Tags: iphone, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an app that utilizes the video camera so the screen cannot dim. Inhibiting the screen from dimming works fine like so:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
}
```

However when the app is closed and enters the background, setting the IdleTimer back to NO is not working. The screen stays on forever on the home screen. This is how I am trying to accomplish this.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
}
```

Is there a better place to add this line of code?

Comment: This may just be a bug with dev builds. I have several apps that force the screen not to dim while they are active, but I've never had one capable of keeping the homescreen or another app on. App settings are almost always app specific to keep the system pure.

Comment: Did you tried this connected to your Mac and XCode? I think that if that the case, the iDevice don't always want to start the "sleep"...

Comment: @Larme, yea that was my first thought but I unhooked it and it still doesn't dim.

Comment: have you tried applicationWillEnterForeground:

Comment: This may sound dumb, but have you checked the sleep interval in settings? This sounds more like a global setting on the phone than an issue with your app

Comment: Did you found a solution? I have the same problem, i'm forcing it to stay on for few minutes then disable it, but is never going to sleep. Yesterday i've got asleep myself and the phone stayed on all night.

Answer (score 16):

The same problem was occurring with me. Actually it does work but only works when your device is not connected to Xcode. Try disconnecting the device and then test this functionality.

Comment: I spend the whole day trying to figure out the problem but it is because of xcode. you saved my life thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using your code in `applicationWillEnterForeground` delegegate method.

Answer (score -1):

**Swift version:**

```
public func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = false
}


public func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
}
```