# Cocos2d and iOS: is there a way to stop the screensaver from starting in my game?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, screensaver

I was wondering if there is a way to **stop the screensaver** (locked screen) from starting on iOS whilst the game is running?

The game I am developing is on Cocos2d for iOS.

What I would like to achieve is:

> "while my game is running I do not want the screensaver to start when
>   normally it would trigger, for example when the user does not tap the
>   screen for a while."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here:
[setIdleTimerDisabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510285/ios-setidletimerdisabledno-not-working)

The property you're looking for is actually called the idle timer. Searching for that may help you find more info on it if the above doesn't work.