# IdleTimerDisabled not working in Xamarin Forms IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, idle-timer

The app I am working on needs to able to keep device awake while the app is the foreground and a particular application user setting is enabled. The below line works fine, however there seems to be no way to turn the idle timer back on. Resetting it to false does not work. Even uninstalling the app and redeploying does not turn it back on.
Does anyone have any insight on this?

// This works great
UIApplication.SharedApplication.IdleTimerDisabled = true;

// This does absolutely nothing
UIApplication.SharedApplication.IdleTimerDisabled = false;

Comment: so when your particular setting is true you need to keep device awake? that is working but once its set , you're unable to reset it?

Comment: @Shubham Tyagi That is exactly the problem. There seems to be no way to reset it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unplugging your device. It might work properly if you run on a device disconnected from your debugger.  See this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510285/ios-setidletimerdisabledno-not-working)

Comment: lol...that fixed it!! Can't believe I didn't try that. Thank you!!